# Echo out element to another page.

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode, forms

I have a small plugin that displays how many submissions are left on current ninja form. And writes it out as so

```
<p id="submissions-left">hurry only 25 submission left. <\p>
```

And tacks it onto the end of the form.  How can I get that p tag to another page? Anyway to target the id and echo it out on another page? Say have a shortcode to use? Thanks

Comment: What is the "small plugin"? Whatever that plugin does to generate the markup posted, can probably be done on other pages as well, but be aware that questions dependent on third party plugin code will likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: A custom plugin was made for me that displayed it at the bottom of the form.  Http://Pastebin.com/vd4Ys8cy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, writing `echo ninja_forms_field_submission_left_display( $field_id, $data );` into a template should do it, if `$field_id` and `$data` is correct.

Creating a shortcode should be equally trivial:

```
function field_sc_wpse_145003($atts,$content) {
  if (!isset($atts['field_id'])) return;
  return ninja_forms_field_submission_left_display( $atts['field_id'], $atts );
}
add_shortcode('fieldfc','field_sc_wpse_145003');

echo do_shortcode('[fieldfc field_id="abc" default_content="def"]');
```

Comment: what do you mean if $field_id and $data are correct? sorry for noob question...

Comment: You have to push two pieces of information to the function.  If those two pieces are correct the function should work.